# How to hide web form from the menu after login if user don't have permission?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I built a website project using ASP.NET c# and the project includes around 30 web forms , then i created users groups each user have access to some web forms depends on his role , then i added the screens to the groups for example booking employees group will access booking web forms , manager group will access all the web forms and screens and so on , now i created the following checkrole void and i put it in page_load to check if the user have this web form under his group then he can access the window otherwise redirect to home page.

This is the CheckRole void :

```
void CheckRoles()
        {
            if (Session["userid"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("/LoginPage.aspx");
            }
            string user_id = Session["userid"].ToString();
            string group_id = func.firesql("select [user_kind_id] from [Users_web] where user_id = '" + user_id + "'");
            string page_current = Request.Url.PathAndQuery.ToString().ToLower();
            string sql = @"SELECT [page_name] FROM [permission_pages] where [group_id]='" + group_id + "' and page_name = '" + page_current + "'";
            string role = func.firesql(sql);

            if (role == "")
            {
                Response.Redirect("/admin/home.aspx");
            }
        }
```

This void working with me but what i need now after login to check the user group and what web forms included and show only the web forms allowed to the user to access and hide the others window from the menu .

How can i make this and show after login only granted web forms and hide the other web forms from the menu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first Create Master Page for All web forms

divide each pages as under category or roles

```
<div id="rol1" runat="server"> 
<page1>
<page2>
<page3>
</div>

<div id="rol2" runat="server"> 
<page1>
<page2>
<page3>
</div>

Or Second Way 
Create UserControls based On role

Role Admin
page1,page2..

Role User
page3,page...
```

User controls more accessible..

Comment: can you give more details please , i created the roles in the database table group_id (1,2,3,4,...) and each group include pages depend on job role.then when create the user add the user to the group. I need after login read the pages and show pages under user group .